# play audio and video files in Cordova app that reside in iOS Documents directory

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, video

I have a Cordova application that I use to be able to link to mp3 and mp4 files relatively using a src like so:

```
../../Documents/videos/video.mp4
```

I just now updated my Cordova application to the latest version and these relative URLs don't work so I've been expermenting with other solutions.

It looks like if I use the `cordova.file.documentsDirectory` (iOS only) variable I can link to them that way but when I save references to these files in the database the GUID of the application changes and the URL is no longer valid when the app is rebuilt and relaunched.

I tried using `cdvfile://localhost/persistent/` but this seems to only work for images and not video or audio files using HTML5 audio and video tags for playback.

Ultimately I could save the files with a variable that gets replaced at run-time but this is obviously not the preferred "solution." Something like `[documentsfolder]/videos/video.mp4`

**How can I link to a persistent file location and have it work with images, audio files, and video files?**

I would love to use the cdvfile url but have it work with mp3 and mp4 files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access any resource [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"www/[your path]"]

Comment: I don't understand the answer. Please explain a bit further.
Note that I'm trying to access a file in the app's Documents folder, not the www folder.